# Excel size grew very large all of a sudden

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

My Excel file(contains macros) that was just 4 MB in size all of a sudden grew into a 12MB file... i made only some minor changes in the vba code and i dont think that is the reason for this....  What else could be the reason for this?  Any Suggestions on how to repair this?

Comment: Images? Formatting? Loading bulk data? : is your macro responsible for that? And clean your code to remove any unused objects. Flushing helps. Any formula that you added to sheets in bulk? Anything not in use, should be dump out. :)

Answer (score 10):

Most likely in the data sheets you have many rows with just formatting. Go into each sheet and delete all rows under the data and then resave the spreadsheet. An easy way to tell is the vertical navigation bar will extend a long way below were your data ends.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a formatting issue. If Philip A Barnes suggestions are not enough (or if you want an automated solution), check the [Microsoft Excel Excess Formatting Cleaner Add-in](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21649)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

If it's not too much to create a new sheet, you may follow this link [help to re-build your sheet](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/223851-rebuild-your-workbook.html)

from above post:

**PURPOSE:**

- decrease filesize
- increase speed
- avoid some strange behaviour of all kind

**WHAT are we talking about ?**

During the development of a workbook+project you are creating, deleting, moving all kinds of items: formats, cells, controls, shapes, modules, variables, .... Some garbage is staying in "the background" of your file. It's like Excel remembers things which are useless for you: f.i. variables which doesn't exist anymore. It's like there are knots in the formulareferences.

So you may read further the entire article to help you with, if you choose this path.

---

With reference to my comment:

"Images? Formatting? Loading bulk data? : is your macro responsible for that? And clean your code to remove any unused objects. Flushing helps. Any formula that you added to sheets in bulk? Anything not in use, should be dump out. :) "

We have usually encountered this issue with following items:-

- links (could be dde links, other third party links like downloading prices, links to other sheets etc)
- formulas (could be working but volatile, could be broken and unused yet triggering)
- pivot tables (old, new)
- formatting, normal and **conditional formatting**
- bulk load of data somewhere that you may not notice

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem with a large excel add-in with plenty of code and then some where it grows from ~5Mb up to ~8Mb with minor code changes. In difference to the fixes in the other answers above, I *do not* change any sheet formatting, it is only code.  I find the following program pretty awesome in knocking back down to size but have been unable to eliminate the problem by other means.

http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm